# How can I preload an SKScene?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Okay so I have to Scenes: TitleScene and GameScene. Obviously there is a lot of stuff in GameScene and that resulted in something very annoying. I have a play-button in the TitleScene and whenever that gets pressed I present the GameScene.

I do that like this:

*In TitleScene.m :*

```
-(void)didMoveToView: (SKView *)view {
    if(!self.contentCreated) {
      self.createSceneContents;
      self.contentCreated = YES;
    }
}

-(void)createSceneContents {

  //among other TitleScene stuff
  self.gameScene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
  self.gameScene.scaleMode = SKScaleModeResizeFill;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
   if ([self.playButton containsPoint:location]) {
          [self.view presentScene:self.gameScene];
   }
}
```

**The Problem is** that whenever I press the play-button it causes like a second to two seconds of lag before transitioning to the next scene.

I create the GameScene just like the TitleScene with a lot of stuff in the createSceneContents method. I know it is not the simulators fault, because I tested it on my iPhone 6.

Can I pre-load all the GameScene's stuff when the app is first opened, or is there another way to stop this lag?

Comment: Run instruments to see where the time is being spent. I had a similar problem and it turned out it was a slightly incorrect name for a font - Instruments showed me that it was a label node and an answer here made me check the font name.

Comment: I have never really used that could you explain/ show me where it is explained

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: I have just noticed that the problem is less problematic when I hold down the button longer

Comment: I used a wrong font too, I fixed it now thanks